# Product of array elements

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, multiplication, emu8086

In this exercise, I need to find the product of the array elements. I wrote the following program but it doesn't seem to work. The correct answer is **-36288**, but I keep getting **49**.

The result I'm after is : -7 x 8 x -9 x 6 x 6 x -2. The number 3 in the array is be ignored.

```
include 'emu8086.inc'

ORG 100h
mov bx, 0
MOV di, 0 
cmp b [di+bx], 3 
je skip
skip: add di,1
cmp di, 7
jle qemer 
qemer: mov Al, b [di + bx]
inc di 
imul b [di+bx] 

CALL pthis
DB 13, 10, 'Result:', 0
CALL print_num; print number in AX.
RET; return to operating system.
b DB 3,-7,8,-9,6,3,6,-2
DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS; required for print_num.
DEFINE_PTHIS
DEFINE_CLEAR_SCREEN
END;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what _"it doesn't seem to work"_ means.

Comment: I mean, the correct answer is - 36288, but I get 49

Comment: Aren't you supposed to iterate over the entire array? I can't see any loop in this code. Also, a conditional jump immedately followed by the jump target is almost always a bug.

Comment: @Michael our teacher taught us loop only with cmp, i don't know other way to do it

Comment: @Michael if it is not a big deal for you, can you correct this (with cmp) for me?

Comment: A loop means that you have a block of one or more instructions that can be executed multiple times in succession. That never happens in your code.

Comment: @Michael yeah, i know but i am new to assembly and at school we are only taught cmp if we need to use loop. so

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use `cmp/jcc` to make a loop, but that's *not* how you've used it.  What you've done is more like an empty `if(){}` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Traversing the array with a loop

This is how your basic loop that traverses the array looks like. I'm sure your teacher's loop will look very similar to this one.

```
  xor  si, si          ; Clears offset into the array
More:
  mov  al, array [si]  ; Reads an element

  ; act on the value

  inc  si              ; Next byte-sized element
  cmp  si, 8           ; Array has 8 bytes
  jb   More            ; Repeat for all value less than 8
```

And because multiplication is commutative, you could just as well traverse the array starting at the end, with the 8th element being at offset +7:

```
  mov  si, 7           ; Offset into the array to the last element
More:
  mov  al, array [si]  ; Reads an element

  ; act on the value

  dec  si              ; Next byte-sized element
  jns  More            ; Repeat for all positive values
```

### What kind of multiplication to use?

The numbers are signed numbers, so you'll have to use the signed multiplication `imul`.
Because the product of the numbers -7, 8, -9, 6, 6, and -2 is -36288, you'll have to use the word-sized version of `imul`. This means that the signed bytes that you read from the array must be sign-extended into `AX` before using them in the multiplication.
And skipping the included numbers 3 is just an added complexity.

```
  mov  bx, 1           ; Initialize the result with the product-neutral value
  xor  si, si
More:
  mov  al, array [si]
  cmp  al, 3           ; Don't use the number 3
  je   Skip
  cbw                  ; Sign-extend AL into AX
  imul bx              ; AX * BX -> DX:AX = {-7, -56, 504, 3024, 18144, -36288}
  mov  bx, ax          ; Update the result in BX
Skip:
  inc  si
  cmp  si, 8
  jb   More
```

### Printing this result is tricky

You are calling *print_num* for this, but this will fail because the result is outside the valid range for a signed word [-32768, +32767]. The screen would show you "29248".
The trick here is to use the unsigned version *print_num_uns* after we have outputted a minus sign and have negated the number in `AX`:

```
  call pthis
  db   13, 10, 'Result:', 0
  putc '-'
  mov  ax, bx
  neg  ax
  call print_num_uns
  ret

array db 3, -7, 8, -9, 6, 3, 6, -2
DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_STRING
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
DEFINE_PTHIS
DEFINE_CLEAR_SCREEN
END
```